# Control Panel - weird error after creating user through zoo

Tags: members, zoo-visitor, registration, register

I am experiencing some weird bugs over the past day or so. Basically we are using Zoo Visitor to allow some of our team to create users without having access to the Members section of the CP, for obvious security reasons, but each time they create a new account over the past day or so, this error is being thrown:

> ExpressionEngine - An unknown error has occurred when sending email with your server.

This same error comes up when trying to update a user's member group. I've run a few searches and I can't find anything that has changed over the past day, but if I knew what caused this error it may be easier to debug properly.

Answer (score 1):

As error states, the error because of the email settings i.e system couldn't send the email.

You need to check the email settings from CP -> Admin -> Email Configuration.

From CP -> Tool -> Communicate, test if email/s are being sent properly by system.

Comment: I've tested the Communicate utility and it works perfectly, so obviously the error is bubbling up from somewhere else. Any ideas?